# How to show AC=BD..

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: diagram]

If we have the picture above, and $AB$ is parallel   to $CD$, also, $\angle{ACB}=\angle {ADB}$, then how to show $AC=BD$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @doobdood, I wanna show $\angle {CAB}=\angle {DBA}$, using the parallel property, we need to show  that $\angle {CBA}=\angle {CDA}$, however, I can't show it.

Comment: *Hint*: $A,B,C,D$ are concyclic.  Now where does the centre lie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to see this, but I wanted to use area.  $(A(\bigtriangleup))$ denotes area of a triangle.

Let the center of the trapezoid be $O$.

Observe:
$$\bigtriangleup COA \sim \; \bigtriangleup DOB$$

Also observe that (from equal height and base):

$$A(\bigtriangleup CBA)=A(\bigtriangleup DAB)$$
Hence:
$$A(\bigtriangleup COA)=A(\bigtriangleup DOB)$$

Similar triangles with equal areas are congruent:
$$AC=BD$$

Answer (score 0):

Call the intersection point $O$. Note that $\triangle AOC$ is similar to $\triangle BOD$, since all angles are same. Also $\triangle OCD$ is similar to $\triangle OBA$ by parallelity. Now call $OC = a$, $OD = b$, $OA = c$ and $OB = d$. By similarity, we have $$\frac{a}{d} = \frac{b}{c}$$ and, by the other similarity, we have, $$\frac{a}{c} = \frac{b}{d}$$ Write $a = \frac{bd}{c}$ in the last equation to get $$\frac{bd}{c^2} = \frac{b}{d}$$ and so $c = d$. Therefore, $\triangle AOC$ and $\triangle BOD$ are the same triangle and the desired line segments are equal.